# Extract URL from curl response

Tags: php, split, preg-match

I have the following response from a PHP curl request:

```
function ___QBy1sZI() {
  YmI = 5849562624174926";
  kNO = "http://download2.website.com/ce0zbkpbzmzg/2g7xednxqx4m11f/blabla.rar";
  output = "";
  for(i=0; i<YmI.length; i+=2){
  output = output + String.fromCharCode( (128+ ( parseInt("0x"+YmI.substr(i, 2)) -           kNO.charCodeAt(0) )) % 128 );
}
return output;
}
```

I want to extract the URL from the response:

```
http://download2.website.com/ce0zbkpbzmzg/2g7xednxqx4m11f/blabla.rar
```

Can anyone tell me what will be the best way? I have used `preg_match` but it seems slow.

Comment: Is the code block you posted the Curl response? And you want to extract the URL from that code block? You should make the question clearer.

Comment: yes!! the code is curl responce....

Comment: Can you please show your regexp for preg-match?

Answer (score 0):

If you say `preg_match()` is "slow", I can only imagine that you are wrongly used it.

Try the following pattern:

```
/kNO = "(.*)";/
```

Matching group[1] will contain the url.

Example:

```
$string = <<<EOF
function ___QBy1sZI() {
  YmI = 5849562624174926";
  kNO = "http://download2.website.com/ce0zbkpbzmzg/2g7xednxqx4m11f/blabla.rar";
  output = "";
  for(i=0; i<YmI.length; i+=2){
  output = output + String.fromCharCode( (128+ ( parseInt("0x"+YmI.substr(i, 2)) -           kNO.charCodeAt(0) )) % 128 );
}
return output;
}
EOF;

preg_match('/kNO = "(.*)";/', $string, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Comment: curl returning 87kb data an it taking up to 5 second

Comment: You wrote: "I got the following response from curl". That's why I thought you showed the complete response. How is the response organized? Can you for example say: "The interesting part is between line 10 and 20" (Or something like that)